# XCDYouTubeVideoPlayer file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I am using `CocoaPods` and have `XCDYouTubeVideoPlayer` as a pod. Recently I had to change my app to support 64-bit, so I upgraded `XCDYoutubeVideoPlayer` to the latest version using `pod install`. I also changed my project to use the `Standard architectures` setting.

After cleaning and trying to run on the device I get the following errors:

[image]

In `Other Linker Flags` I am using `$(inherited)`.

Strangely, I can archive the project successfully without errors.

**Any advice on how I can fix this?**

Answer (score 1):

I've been using `XCDYouTubeVideoPlayer` recently too and been cross-checking my project settings with regards to it.

**Other Linker Flags**:

```
$(inherited)
-l"Pods-XCDYouTubeKit"
```

**Header Search Paths**

```
$(inherited)
"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/XCDYouTubeKit"
```

**Framework Search Paths**

```
$(inherited)
```

All shown entries are for `Debug` and `Release` the same

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Still getting a `ld: library not found for -lPods-XCDYouTubeKit` error.

Comment: Maybe try to remove it from cocoapoda, do install, add it again and do install again

Comment: Or before 2nd install try to build your project, if it stillgives you the error you should have a reference to it somewhere else

Comment: I just don't understand why I am able to archive the project successfully, but not build for the device. I thought the process was similar since they are both Release.